# scons: Unnecessarily rebuilds files during the first time-stamp only build

Tags: scons

I am doing a timestamp-only build to bulk convert image files.  Many of the converted image files already exist, but I like to make sure that they are all checked through each time.

How come SCons requires a database file (`.sconsign.dblite`) that it uses for MD5 hash data when it's instructed (via `env.Decider("timestamp-newer")`) to only deal with timestamps?  It shouldn't need to keep a database between builds for timestamps because all the information is associated with the files themselves.

If the dblite database doesn't exist SCons reconverts all the images regardless of whether their timestamps imply they need to be rebuilt or not.  The title is an example message I get when the dblite database does not exist.

If anyone can explain this I'd really appreciate it.  I love the functional programming with Python, but SCons itself is not quite doing it for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Using "timestamp-newer", SCons actually stores the timestamp info. You can see why here:

[Using Time Stamps to Decide If a File Has Changed](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c824.html#AEN898)

Try using "timestamp-match" instead.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work for me.  It still depends on a pre-existing database of timestamps and if it doesn't exist (i.e. first time SCons is run) it still rebuilds the files.  SCons comes up with:


`scons: Cannot explain why `jpg-1024px/DSCF1502-1024px.JPG' is being rebuilt: No previous build information found`

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to do? Removing the ".sconsign.dblite" file and hoping that it works is a non-standard use of the application. The error message (and resulting SCons behaviour)  seems more than reasonable to me. Does SCons work as expected without removing said file with one of the Decider() options?

Comment: Bulk conversion of image files.  Consider a large selection of images that you add some to, or alter a few of.  Means you don't have to keep track of every image you changed or added manually when converting.
It does the _second_ time it is run.  It seems that when it is creating the database file it is rebuilding files when in reality it does not have to based on the timestamps alone.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this sorted. Brady was right about how to use SCons, but I a few days ago I eventually worked out you can also control exactly what you want built by just controlling what build commands are issued in the first place. In my case I ignored any image files for which the target file already exists using `os.path.exists()`.

Sounds simple, but it is a conceptual difference between `SCons` and `make`, because `make` does not save its state between builds in the way SCons does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm trying to work out the same thing, but I'm doing bulk conversion of video files which takes several days if done unnecessarily.  I've already done most of it.

So I want a way to tell SCons, "For files that exist *now*, store their existing timestamps/MD5s, and don't rebuild unless that changes in *future*."

Will report back if I find a way...

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is really about why there's a .sconsign.dblite when you set the decider to just check timestamp.

One reason is that it allows SCons to keep track of the method used to produce each target. If that changes, even if the timestamp doesn't, it should rebuild the affected targets.

Have you tried building a single file, and then using the sconsign utility to examine the contents of the .sconsign.dblite file?